# Applying Razorpay payment gateway fail to get form response asp.net 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to apply a payment gateway razorpay to my request page and i want to send the response data to response page. in the reponse page i am using the Request.Form method to get the form data but data is recieved is null. i am using asp.net framework version 4.7.2

**my requestpage.aspx code is below.**

```
 <form action="https://localhost:47851/RazorPayCallBack.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="hwer" name="hwer" value="xyz"/>
    <script
        src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
        data-key="MY PAYMENT KEY";
        data-amount="<%=amount%>"
        data-name="TEST TRANSACTION"
        data-description="TEST DATA AMOUNT"
        data-order_id="<%=OrderId%>"
        data-image="https://razorpay.com/favicon.png"
        data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
        data-prefill.name="<%=PersonName%>"
        data-prefill.email="<%=Email%>"
        data-prefill.contact="<%=Mobile%>">
    </script>

</form>
```

**And this is my RazorPayCallBack.aspx code behind for getting data**

```
 public partial class RazorPayCallBack : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        try
        {
            string name =Request.Form["razorpay_payment_id"]; // value is null here 
            string paymentId =Request.Form["razorpay_payment_id"]; // value is null here
            string orderId = Request.Form["razorpay_order_id"]; // value is null here 
            string signature =Request.Form["razorpay_signature"]; // value is null here

            string key = "MY KEY"; 
            string secret = "MY SECRET KEY";

            RazorpayClient client = new RazorpayClient(key, secret);

            Dictionary<string, string> attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            attributes.Add("razorpay_payment_id", paymentId);
            attributes.Add("razorpay_order_id", orderId);
            attributes.Add("razorpay_signature", signature);

            Utils.verifyPaymentSignature(attributes);
            pTxtId.InnerText = paymentId;
            pOrdId.InnerText = orderId;
            msg.InnerText = "Transaction Successfull";
        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            msg.InnerText = "Transaction Unsuccessfull";
        }
    }
}
```

i want the value of orderid, payment id on my RazorPayCallBack.aspx page Please help me with providing the right solution....

Answer (score 0):

nimesh in the requestpage.aspx there is a form element as shown below

"  "

try removing the file extention ".aspx" in the form tag, the form tag should look something like shown below

""

For more information please check out the below link
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/293/request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page